# Whole file not read

Tags: c, file

I have a file which contains a set of numbers.
I'm trying to read those numbers into an array. I'm allocating memory for that array using a pointer and reading from the file into the location. 
For some reason, the program does not read beyond 5 values from the file.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    int i=0, count=0;
    //unsigned long int num[1000];
    unsigned long int *ptr;
    ptr = (unsigned long int*) malloc (sizeof(unsigned long int));
    char file1[30], file2[30];
    int bin[1000][32];
    int ch;

    argv++;
    strcpy(file1,*argv);

    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen(file1, "r");

    while((fscanf(fp,"%ld",ptr))==1)
    {
        ptr++;
        count++;
    }

    ptr=ptr-count;
    for(i=0; i<count;i++,ptr++)
        printf("%ld\n",*ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

The input file contains the following:

```
1206215586
3241580200
3270055958
2720116784
3423335924
1851806274
204254658
2047265792
19088743
```

The output is just this:

```
1206215586
3241580200
3270055958
2720116784
3423335924
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are trying to read more than one value into memory only big enough for one value.

Answer (score 2):

You need to allocate enough space to store your integers in. To do this , use the `realloc` function on the original pointer.

The fact that you write `ptr++` makes it awkward to call `realloc` on the original pointer and save the result. So it would be a better idea to not use `ptr++`. Instead you can use `ptr[count]` and leave `ptr` always pointing to the start of the allocation.

For example the main loop could be:

```
while((fscanf(fp,"%lu",&ptr[count]))==1)
{
    count++;

    void *new = realloc(ptr,  (count+1) * sizeof(*ptr));
    if ( !new )
        break;      // maybe print error message, etc.

    ptr = new;           
}

// don't do this any more
//     ptr=ptr-count;
```

Comment: Note: `void *new = ...` is one way to insure this code does not compiled with C++. ;-)